# Iterate over a list to create a parent/child dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Assuming I have the following list:

```
l = [['01', 'pharma', 'P'],['02', 'y', '01'],['03', 'x', '01'],['05', 'z', '03']]
```

where the elements in each nested list are key, name and parent_key, respectively. If the parent_key is 'P', it means it is the grand parent.

Example:

The third element in ['02', 'y', '01'] is '01' is the parent_key for 'y' which means it is a child of 'pharma' which has '01' as a key.

I want to create a parent/child dictionary that I can query to print the following:

```
pharma
 x
  z
 y
```

where 'pharma' is the parent, 'x' and 'y' are children of 'pharma' and 'z' is a child of 'x'. Each child is indented with one space than its parent.

what I have tried is the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    d[i[0]] = []
    if i[2] in d.keys():
        d[i[2]].append(i[1])
```

But it doesn't produce the required output

Comment: Do you need to preserve the indexing keys, i.e. ``01``, ``02`` and so on? Is there a reason why your second level stores names and not the keys?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no the indexing keys are not important. I want to display the parent and its children/grandchildren without their keys, if that makes sense?

Comment: Are keys and names unique, or can the same name apply to multiple names?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi they are unique.

Comment: Are parents and children sorted, i.e. does a child always appear after its parent has been defined already?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, they can appear anywhere in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each name belongs to only one key, and parents are defined before their children, you need to do *three* tasks for each element:

1. map its name to a yet incomplete child list
2. map its ID to its name
3. link it to its parent

If parents and children are not ordered, i.e. a child can appear before its parent, you must build 1. and 2. separately from 3.
Otherwise, you can do everything in one pass over your data. Note that instead of indexing into elements, you can destructure the element in the for loop.

```
key2name = {}
name2children = {}
for key, name, parent in l:
    name2children[name] = []  # 1.
    key2name[key] = name      # 2.
    if parent != 'P':         # root node has no parent
        name2children[key2name[parent]].append(name) # 3.
```

For your example, this produces the structure

```
{'pharma': ['y', 'x'], 'x': ['z'], 'y': [], 'z': []}
```

Note that your data is *not* sorted to match your desired output!

---

You can pretty print this as desired by walking this tree. The `sorted` call can be dropped if you do not care about ordering.

```
def printwalk(node, indent=0):
    print(' '*indent, node)
    for child in sorted(name2children[node]):
        printwalk(child, indent+1)
printwalk('pharma')
# pharma
#  x
#   z
#  y
```

---

This is the case if parents and children are not ordered. You must separately initialise the translation (1) and parent->child (2) containers.

```
key2name = {}
name2children = {}
for key, name, _ in l:
    name2children[name] = []  # 1.
    key2name[key] = name      # 2.

for key, name, parent in l:
    if parent != 'P':         # root node has no parent
        name2children[key2name[parent]].append(name) # 3.
```

Comment: That worked well for when the parents and children are ordered. When they are not ordered, do you mean that `name2children = {name: [] for _, name, _ in l}` would replace the empty dictionary before the for loop?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that both ``name2children`` *and* ``key2name`` must be built beforehand in this case. Updating...