# Python - How to convert a list of dictionaries with tree items?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a list of dictionaries with id links:

```
[
    { 'id': 1, 'parent_id': None,   'title': '1', },
    { 'id': 3, 'parent_id': 1,  'title': '1.1', },
    { 'id': 5, 'parent_id': 4,  'title': '1.2.1', },
    { 'id': 2, 'parent_id': None,   'title': '2', },
    { 'id': 4, 'parent_id': 1,  'title': '1.2', }
]
```

I need to create an tree object that looks like this:

```
[
    { 'id': 1,'title': '1', 'children': [
                    {'id': 3, 'title': '1.1', 'children': []},
                    {'id': 4, 'title': '1.2', 'children': [
                                {'id': 5, 'title': '1.2.1', 'children': []},
                                                        ]},
                                    ]},
    { 'id': 2,  'title': '2', 'children': []},
]
```

How can i do that in Python? Thanks for helping!

UPD
I tried this one, but I don’t know how to write code that worked at the 2 level and more.

```
    for element in elements_list:
    if not element.get('parent_id'):
        menu.append({
            'id': element.get('id'),
            'title': element.get('title'),
            'children': []
        })
    else:
        for item in menu:
            if item.get('id') == element.get('parent_id'):
                item.get('children').append({
                    'title': element.get('title'),
                    'children': []
                })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over a list to create a parent/child dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569702/iterate-over-a-list-to-create-a-parent-child-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
[{'id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'title': '1'}, {'id': 3, 'parent_id': 1, 'title': '1.1'}, {'id': 5, 'parent_id': 4, 'title': '1.2.1'}, {'id': 2, 'parent_id': None, 'title': '2'}, {'id': 4, 'parent_id': 1, 'title': '1.2'}]
def _filter(_d):
  return {a:b for a, b in _d.items() if a != 'parent_id'}

def group_vals(_d, _start = None):
  return [_filter({**i, 'children':group_vals(_d, i['id'])})
         for i in _d if i['parent_id'] == _start]

print(group_vals(d))
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': '1', 'children': [
     {'id': 3, 'title': '1.1', 'children': []}, 
     {'id': 4, 'title': '1.2', 'children': [{'id': 5, 'title': '1.2.1', 'children': []}]}]}, 
  {'id': 2, 'title': '2', 'children': []}]
```

Comment: Is ```d``` the initial list in ```print(group_vals(d))```?